# Finding solutions to a system of equations: $b+c=46_a b\times c=545_a$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Whenever i try to solve this system of equation i fail and don't even know where to get started:

$b+c=46_a$

$b\times c=545_a$

$1\le a < b < c, (a,b,c) \in \mathbb{N}$

## Edit:

I tried to solve the equation:
$x^2-46_ax+545_a=0$ , But was not able to continue and things were getting to be messy.

Comment: $46_a = 4\times a^1 + 6\times a^0=4a+6$

Comment: It's actually $x^2-46_ax+545_a=0$.

Comment: Exactly, really sorry about the typo!.

Comment: using WolframAlpha, $a=2$ $b=3$, and $c=11$, but i couldn't hack that manually.

Comment: many solutions actually, that was one of them.